# Plotting level sets of Hamiltonians on the product of 2 spheres

Tags: plotting

Suppose I have the $S^2\times S^2$ with standard coordinates $(x_1,y_1,z_1,x_2,y_2,z_2)$. I want to consider the following Hamiltonians $(J,H)(x_1,y_1,z_1,x_2,y_2,z_2):=(z_1+z_2,\frac{1}{2}z_1+\frac{1}{2}(x_1x_2+y_1y_2+z_1z_2))$. Now I would like to obtain the following level sets $(J,H)^{-1}((a,b))$ plotted in Mathematica. Does anyone know how I can write the code to do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need to provide more details and the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 3):

- The code here only demonstrate the principle which the questioner want to plot.
- Since we still not able to found the faster way to draw the two regions in the two unit spheres respectively, so it is only a starting point.

```
Clear[cond, sol, reg1, reg2, bd, plot];
cond = Exists[{x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, 
    z2}, {{x1, y1, z1} . {x1, y1, z1} == 
     1, {x2, y2, z2} . {x2, y2, z2} == 1}, {a, b} == {z1 + z2, 
     z1/2 + {x1, y1, z1} . {x2, y2, z2}/2}];
sol = Resolve[cond, Reals];
reg1 = ImplicitRegion[sol, {a, b}];
bd = RegionBounds[reg1];
plot = RegionPlot[sol, {a, b} ∈ Rectangle @@ Transpose@bd, 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Yellow, 
   FrameLabel -> {Style["a", Blue, 15], Style["b", Blue, 15]}];
reg2 = DiscretizeGraphics[plot];
plot
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[Module[{p, q, x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2},
  {p, q} = {{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}} /. 
    NMaximize[{0, {x1, y1, z1} . {x1, y1, z1} == 
        1, {x2, y2, z2} . {x2, y2, z2} == 1, 
       pt == {z1 + z2, z1/2 + {x1, y1, z1} . {x2, y2, z2}/2}}, {x1, 
       y1, z1, x2, y2, z2}][[2]];
  {Graphics3D[{{Opacity[.5], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1]}, {Red, 
      AbsolutePointSize[10], Point[p]}, {Opacity[.5], 
      Sphere[{2, 2, 0}, 1]}, {Blue, AbsolutePointSize[10], 
      Point[q + {2, 2, 0}]}}, Boxed -> False], 
   Graphics[{Yellow, reg2, Point[pt]}]}], {{pt, {0, 0}}, Locator, 
  TrackingFunction -> (pt = RegionNearest[reg2, #]; &)}]
```

[image]

- Finally we found that for any `{a,b}` the level set is the Cartesian product of two bands of the unit spheres

```
Clear["Global`*"];
cond = Exists[{x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2}, {x1^2 + y1^2 + z1^2 == 1, 
    x2^2 + y2^2 + z2^2 == 1}, {a, b} == {z1 + z2, 
     z1/2 + {x1, y1, z1} . {x2, y2, z2}/2}];
sol = Resolve[cond, Reals];
reg0 = ImplicitRegion[sol, {a, b}];
bd = RegionBounds[reg0];
plot = RegionPlot[sol, {a, b} ∈ Rectangle @@ Transpose@bd, 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Yellow, 
   FrameLabel -> {Style["a", Blue, 15], Style["b", Blue, 15]}];
reg0 = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[plot];
regm = RegionMember[reg0];
tworegs[{a1_, b1_} /; regm@{a1, b1}] := 
 Module[{reg, sol1, reg1, sol2, reg2, a, b}, {a, b} = 
   Rationalize[{a1, b1}, 0];
  reg = ImplicitRegion[{a, b} == {z1 + z2, 
      z1/2 + {x1, y1, z1} . {x2, y2, z2}/2}, {x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2}];
  sol1 = 
   Simplify[
    Resolve[Exists[{x2, y2, z2}, 
      x2^2 + y2^2 + z2^2 == 1, {x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2} ∈ 
       reg]], {x1^2 + y1^2 + z1^2 == 1, -1 <= x1 <= 1, -1 <= y1 <= 
      1, -1 <= z1 <= 1}];
  reg1 = 
   RegionIntersection[ImplicitRegion[sol1, {x1, y1, z1}], Sphere[]];
  sol2 = 
   Simplify[
    Resolve[Exists[{x1, y1, z1}, 
      x1^2 + y1^2 + z1^2 == 1, {x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2} ∈ 
       reg]], {x2^2 + y2^2 + z2^2 == 1, -1 <= x2 <= 1, -1 <= y2 <= 
      1, -1 <= z2 <= 1}];
  reg2 = 
   RegionIntersection[ImplicitRegion[sol2, {x2, y2, z2}], Sphere[]];
  {HighlightMesh[
    DiscretizeRegion[reg1, MaxCellMeasure -> ∞, 
     AccuracyGoal -> 1], {Style[1, None], Style[2, Red]}], 
   HighlightMesh[
    DiscretizeRegion[reg2, MaxCellMeasure -> ∞, 
     AccuracyGoal -> 1], {Style[1, None], Style[2, Blue]}]}]
DynamicModule[{pt = {1/2, 1/2}}, 
 ClickPane[
  Dynamic@{tworegs@pt, 
    Graphics[{Yellow, reg0, Black, Locator@pt}]}, (pt = 
     RegionNearest[reg0, #]) &]]
```

[image]